# Recording number of search results from Google

Tags: vba, excel

I have an some text in column B and I am trying to record the number of Google search results in column C. The search will give me this page below and I will need the number of search results from here:
[Google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3jfS.png)

The code I am using is this:

```
Sub HawkishSearch()

Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 2) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

If html.getElementById("resultStats") Is Nothing Then
    str_text = "0 Results"
Else
    str_text = html.getElementById("resultStats").innerText
End If
    Cells(i, 3) = str_text
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

There are two problems with this code.

Firstly, I get the whole result "About xxxx results (x.xx seconds)". I need just the number of search results. I tried using:

```
Cells(i, 3) = Mid(str_text, 7, Len(str_text) - 30)
```

but it will give me an error in case there's for example 0 results.

Secondly, and most importantly, I am getting the error at `XMLHTTP.send`:

[image: Access is denied 80070005]

Comment: P.S. IS this the reason I am getting the errors? In that case, can somebody suggest whether this is at all doable?

 https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-VBA-code-that-I-can-use-to-extract-the-Google-search-results-in-Excel-from-an-Internet-Explorer-page

Answer (score 0):

change 
`Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`

to

`Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`